# Is it always true that if there is only one subsequential limit point of a sequence, then the sequence must converge to it?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

If x is the only subsequential limit point of a sequence, is it always true that the sequence converges to x?

I know that if a sequence converges to some point x, then every subsequence also converges to that point. So there is only one subsequential limit. But I'm trying to figure out if the other direction works; if there is only one subsequential limit, doesn't that imply that the sequence converges to it?

Comment: Under what assumptions (e.g., what if the sequence has only one limit point and $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded)? What do you know? What have you tried?

Comment: I know that if a sequence converges to some point x, then every subsequence also converges to that point. So there is only one subsequential limit. But I'm trying to figure out if the other direction works; if there is only one subsequential limit, doesn't that imply that the sequence converges to it?

Comment: Although I see you've accepted an answer, I should note that the answer is affirmative for (in increasing levels of sophistication): bounded sequences of reals, bound sequences in $\mathbb{R}^n$, sequences in compact metric spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this:

$a_n=1,1,1,2,1,3,1,4....$

i.e $a_n=1 $ if $ n$ is even
and $a_n=\frac{n+1}{2}$ if  $n$ is odd

$1$ is the only subsequential limit

Comment: Slight nitpick: $a_n = \frac{n+1}{2}$ in your sequence for odd $n$ (assuming we're starting at $a_0$)

Comment: yes i have edited that thanks@JHance